# Removing duplicate elements in a list with sets of arrays in python

Tags: python-3.x, duplicates, datalist

I have a list[(position,id)] from the user based on the ids it chooses which I collect in **data**

```
data[(position,id)] = [(1,0),(2,0),(7,3),(8,6),(3,11),(3,11),(4,0),(5,1),(5,1),(6,2),(9,5),(10,7),(15,0),(16,10),(11,0),(11,1),(12,15),(13,8),(13,8),(13,9),(14,9)]
```

There are some duplicate elements in the list which I sorted out using *set(list) command

```
listdata = data
res=[]
res = [*set(listdata)]
print(res)
```

I get the res list as follows:

```
output: res = [(11, 1), (13, 8), (6, 2), (4, 0), (16, 10), (11, 0), (2, 0), (5, 1), (10, 7), (7, 3), (9, 5), (15, 0), (13, 9), (14, 9), (8, 6), (12, 15), (1, 0), (3, 11)]
```

But what I want is only 16 elements in the list on first come basis with positions 1 to 16, if you see here I have got 2 entries with position 11 [(11,1),(11,0)] and position 13[(13,8),(13,9)]

Required output:
`res=[(11, 1), (13, 8), (6, 2), (4, 0), (16, 10), (2, 0), (5, 1), (10, 7), (7, 3), (9, 5), (15, 0), (14, 9), (8, 6), (12, 15), (1, 0), (3, 11)]`

Can anyone suggest alternate solution?

Comment: How about Res[:16]?

Comment: @shrewmouse it does gives me 16 values but just first 16 values, that can involve position duplicacy as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use a map to record every position only once

```
data = [(1,0),(2,0),(7,3),(8,6),(3,11),(3,11),(4,0),(5,1),(5,1),(6,2),(9,5),(10,7),(15,0),(16,10),(11,0),(11,1),(12,15),(13,8),(13,8),(13,9),(14,9)]
bucket = {}
for d in data:
    bucket[d[0]] = d[1]
print(list(bucket.items()))
```

output is:

```
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (7, 3), (8, 6), (3, 11), (4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 2), (9, 5), (10, 7), (15, 0), (16, 10), (11, 1), (12, 15), (13, 9), (14, 9)]
```

---

update:
I am sorry I missed the description: "But what I want is only 16 elements in the list on first come basis", my answer above keeps the later came value, if you want to keep the first came one, do something like this:

```
data = [(1,0),(2,0),(7,3),(8,6),(3,11),(3,11),(4,0),(5,1),(5,1),(6,2),(9,5),(10,7),(15,0),(16,10),(11,0),(11,1),(12,15),(13,8),(13,8),(13,9),(14,9)]
bucket = {}
for d in data:
    if d[0] not in bucket:
        # if you never seen it, keep it, else ingore it. 
        bucket[d[0]] = d[1]
print(list(bucket.items()))
```

Comment: This isn't right at all.  This will give you the last id for each position not the first id.  You only get (11,1) because you put (11,1) after (11,0).  If you run your solution on the given input your solution will produce `[(11, 0), (13, 9), (6, 2), (4, 0), (16, 10), (2, 0), (5, 1), (10, 7), (7, 3), (9, 5), (15, 0), (14, 9), (8, 6), (12, 15), (1, 0), (3, 11)]` .  `(11,0)` is wrong.

Comment: @shrewmouse yes, but this is another topic, you should determine your strategy of keep which one.

Comment: No, it's not another topic.  OP specifically said, "But what I want is only 16 elements in the list on first come basis".

Comment: @shrewmouse thanks for point out this, I missed the key word "first come", and answer is updated.

Comment: Thank you @shrewmouse and Xi for the support. I get what I require as my output

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be done with a generator.

```
res = [(11, 1), (13, 8), (6, 2), (4, 0), (16, 10), (11, 0), (2, 0), (5, 1), (10, 7), (7, 3), (9, 5), (15, 0), (13, 9), (14, 9), (8, 6), (12, 15), (1, 0), (3, 11)]


def foo(_res, max_items):
    keys = []
    for k,v in _res:
        if k not in keys:
            yield (k,v)
            keys.append(k)

        if len(keys) > max_items:
            return

print(list(foo(res, 16)))
```

output:

```
[(11, 1), (13, 8), (6, 2), (4, 0), (16, 10), (2, 0), (5, 1), (10, 7), (7, 3), (9, 5), (15, 0), (14, 9), (8, 6), (12, 15), (1, 0), (3, 11)]
```